# RegEx for Javascript (replace function) to allow only letters and spaces, but not start with space?

Tags: javascript, regex

Well, in the `keydown` event of a textbox I need (with `regex` and `replace`):

1. The first character don't be space.
2. Allow only letters.
3. Allow a one space only in the whole string between words. But, how
       its in a `keydown` event, if the user keeps the space key pressed,
       it only has to be a one space in the textbox.

Some examples:

**don't pass** `' My name is'` (the first character is space)

**pass** `'My name is '` (doesn't matter space)

**don't pass** `'My name is 123'` (contain numbers)

I have tried this to work with only one space:

```
replace(/\s+/g,' ');
```

and works, but I don't know how to do it with the other things in the same regex.

Comment: Do that with 2 regular expressions. It is fine to use 2 expressions to make 2 independent checks/replacements.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, but I need an example !

Comment: An example of what exactly? There are millions of articles about regular expressions.

Comment: of what I want to do. I have tried with differents solutions, but I don't get it

Comment: So you want the community to implement it for you? What you asked about is really trivial things. Did you even try to **learn** regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it:

**Html**

```
<input type="text" id="target">
```

**Js**

```
$( "#target" ).keyup(function() {
  var str = $(this).val();
  var res = str.replace(/\d+|^\s+$/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
  $(this).val(res);
});
```

Maybe my question was not too clear, but you can see a finally result in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/890r9wh4/4/)

**EDIT:**

To not allow special characters, it is needed to declare them:

```
str.replace(/[\"\'~`!@#$%^&()_={}[\]:;,.<>+\/?-]+|\d+|^\s+$/g, '').replace(/\s+/ig, ' ')
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: the question would have received been much better if you'd included a fiddle there, and a summary of what you'd attempted.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The next time I'll do it. Thanks for your suggestion !

Comment: This doesn't just allow letters and spaces... any special character other than numbers is allowed... even emojis...

Comment: @BrittonPentakill I have edited my answer, exactly 3 years later :)

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do it

```
/^[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z\s]+$/
```

Breakdown

`^` - Start of line

`[A-Za-z]` - Any letter

`{1}` - Exactly one letter

`[A-Za-z\s]` - Either a letter or a whitespace character

`+` - One or more

`$` - End of line

Comment: But, how could be with `replace`?